# Kubernetes on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Im trying to run my app on GCE cluster but I think Im missing something connected to the kubernetes resources for deployment. I have 4 deployments with respectively 3 deployments with 2 replicaset (with autoscale set) and 1 deployment with 1 replicaset (daemons). From my initial understanding and calculations I've tried to set requests of: 400m vCPU and 1500M RAM and limits to: 500m and 1800M RAM for all of my deployments. After setting those resources my pod weren't runing because of insufficient cpu and memory. After reading more docs of kubernetes it look like kubernetes kube-system is taking some of the cluster resources so in the end Im able to manage only X% (not 100%) of my 4 node cluster (4vCpu & 15GB ram). So im trying to understand how much exactly does kubernetes take so i know what values are under my full control of this cluster resources but I cant figure it out what resources and limits will be best suited.
Can anyone help me with this??

Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

> how much exactly does kubernetes take

You can examine the node's 'allocatable' capacity by running `kubectl describe node`. In general it's like

`[Allocatable] = [Node Capacity] - [Kube-Reserved] - [System-Reserved] - [Hard-Eviction-Threshold]`

Actual values will differ based on environment and configuration.

More on this subject here: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/node-allocatable.md